# Зачем использовать namespace?

Tags: php

Зачем использовать namespace?

Зачем использовать namespace отдельно для одного класса когда можно обойтись без него так как сам namespace и самое имя класса в глобальном пространстве будут занимать одинаково количество места?

Если есть ссылки на статьи объясняющие зачем и почему, прошу скинуть мне, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 5):

[PHP: Правильный путь](http://getjump.me/ru-php-the-right-way/) - очень хорошее руководство как для начинающих, так и для опытных разработчиков. Цитирую из данного руководства:

> Как описано в руководстве PHP,
>   пространства имен можно сравнить с папками операционной системы,
>   которые являются пространствами имен файлов; два файла с одинаковым
>   именем могут сосуществовать в разных директориях. Подобно этому, два
>   PHP класса с одинаковым названием могут существовать в разных
>   пространствах имен PHP.
>
> Использование пространств имен необходимо для того, чтобы избежать
>   конфликтов при использовании вашего кода с библиотеками других
>   разработчиков.

Answer (score 4):

Поскольку мы уже давно выходим за рамки homepage существует риск переопределить какие-то функции написанные кем то другим. Namespace позволяют нам держать наши перлы в своих ограниченных пространствах. Не хочется отделять мух от тараканов - не делайте этого. Но когда вы в реальном проекте исправив одну ошибку сделаете 20 других вам покажется, что все же лучше ограничить видимость ваших функций.